sox became buggy after MacOS upgrade to Ventura 13.6.5
I installed sox using homebrew. It ran without problems when I was using Big Sur (10.16). However, after updating to Ventura (13.6.5), when I try to play an audio file, it freezes with the following output:
$ play sox.wav

sox.wav:

 File Size: 67.6k     Bit Rate: 353k
  Encoding: Signed PCM
  Channels: 1 @ 16-bit
Samplerate: 22050Hz
Replaygain: off
  Duration: 00:00:01.53

In:0.00% 00:00:00.00 [00:00:01.53] Out:0     [      |      ]        Clip:0

I can play this file in e.g. Audacity, and even MacOs's afplay. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling using homebrew, and also updating homebrew, to no avail.
I suspect there's a bug somewhere in one of the libraries. Can anyone suggest what can be done to get sox working again?

It turned out the problem was because of my having soundflower and background music installed. I forgot how I installed them, but these are not well supported by Ventura, and sox haven't quite ignored them.
